# Pass variables with PHP that have '&' on them

Tags: php

I'm passing this URL with Ajax to a PHP file: `amazon.com/?ie=UTF8&showViewpo`

My problem is with the '&' on the URL.

`$_POST['site']` will echo `amazon.com/`

How can I pass the variable so as to be able to get it whole on my PHP file?

Comment: What code are you using in Javascript?

Comment: I'm now trying with jQuery: `$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'insert/insert-history.php',data:"user="+uid+"&site="+siteAurl`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with putting spaces in $_GET variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364793/whats-wrong-with-putting-spaces-in-get-variables)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it. That will make it safe to pass in a url.

**Update**

Didn't read the question correctly.

You have to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to urlencode it in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `$.ajax` will automatically urlencode your variables if you pass key/values for data instead of a string:

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'insert/insert-history.php',data: {user: uid, site: siteAurl }});
```