# $_GET value from URL that contains space

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a clickable row and a textbox which value is the name clicked on the row, easy. This is a sample of my code.
The table :

```
<table border="2">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Categorie number</td>
                <td>Categorie name</td>
            </tr>
                <?php
                    $SQLCategorie = mysqli_query($db,'SELECT * FROM categorie ORDER BY Name_categorie');
                    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($SQLCategorie))
                    {
                        echo '<td>' .$row[0]. '</td>';
                            echo "<td><a href='GererCategorie.php?Name_categorie=".$row[1]."' >".$row[1]."</a></td>";  
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                ?>  
        </tbody>
</table>
```

And the textbox :

```
<input type="text" name="Delete_Categorie" 
                    <?php 
                        if (isset($_GET['Name_categorie'])) 
                        {
                            echo "value=".$_GET['Name_categorie'];
                        }
                    ?>
>
```

Everything works fine but I have a weird problem. For example I have `INTERNET EXPLORER` in my database and my URL looks like `?Name_categorie=INTERNET%20EXPLORER`. The textbox only shows `INTERNET`, I CANNOT echo `INTERNET EXPLORER`.

I know that my probleme may seem easy but I have no idea how to echo the full name. I need to get it because I have `EXCEL 2003` and `EXCEL 2010` but it only shows EXCEL. For `EXCEL 2010` I have in my URL `EXCEL%202010`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with putting spaces in $\_GET variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364793/whats-wrong-with-putting-spaces-in-get-variables)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but the code seems vulnerable to that issue, so take a look at it anyway @Hearner :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the HTML you are generating, your output will look something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Delete_Categorie" value=INTERNET EXPLORER>
```

So the browser will read this as value being `INTERNET`, and EXPLORER will be interpreted as an attribute name.

You need to add quotes around your text.

```
echo "value=\"".$_GET['Name_categorie']."\"";
```

This will output

```
<input type="text" name="Delete_Categorie" value="INTERNET EXPLORER">
```

Comment: PERFECT Thank you, that solved my problem. Now I understand,I had not thought about it

Comment: I can't click `This answer is helpful` though

Comment: @Hearner you can accept it. Press the tick underneath the 0

Comment: Ow yes sorry i did not know. Thank you @Loko

Answer (score 1):

You need to `urlencode()`

```
echo "<td><a href='GererCategorie.php?Name_categorie=".urlencode($row[1])."' >".$row[1]."</a></td>";
```

and then `urldecode()`

```
echo "value=".urldecode($_GET['Name_categorie']);
```

Comment: It adds `+` between the words. `EXCEL 2010` becomes `EXCEL+2010`

Comment: `rawurldecode()` and `rawurlencode()` makes/moves percent signs you are facing in code.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative,
you could [replace](http://php.net/str_replace) a white space with a _ before using it in the `href=""` and then after you get the value of the textbox you can [replace](http://php.net/str_replace) the _ with a whitespace again.

Example:

```
echo "<td><a href='GererCategorie.php?Name_categorie=".str_replace(' ', '_',$row[1])."' >".$row[1]."</a></td>";
```

and in your value:

```
echo "value=".str_replace('_', ' ',$_GET['Name_categorie']);
```